# How to import only non existing row from csv and update existing rows to SQL Database C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, csv

With the help from the sylvan.data.csv package i'm now able to apply the scheme from the sql table to the csv. Yet the following problem arises where i want to check if a row from the csv exists in the sql database. If it does, it needs to be updated and if it does not only the non existing rows need to be imported. But with a bulkcopy this is not possible.

I've got the following code:

```
        static void LoadTableCsv(SqlConnection conn, string tableName, string csvFile)
        {

            // read the column schema of the target table
            var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            conn.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = $"select top 0 * from {tableName}"; // beware of sql injection
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            var colSchema = reader.GetColumnSchema();
            reader.Close();

            // apply the column schema to the csv reader.
            var csvSchema = new CsvSchema(colSchema);
            var csvOpts = new CsvDataReaderOptions { Schema = csvSchema };
            using var csv = CsvDataReader.Create(csvFile, csvOpts);

            // Initialize SqlCommand for checking if the record already exists.
            using var checkCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {tablename} WHERE TicketID = @value", conn);
            checkCommand.Parameters.Add("@value", SqlDbType.Int, 10, "TicketID");


            using var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn);
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = tableName;
            bulkCopy.EnableStreaming = true;

            // Iterate through the records in the CSV file.
            while (csv.Read())
            {
                // Set the value of the "@value" parameter
                checkCommand.Parameters["@value"].Value = csv["TicketID"].ToString();

                // Execute the check command to see if the record already exists.
                var checkResult = (int)checkCommand.ExecuteScalar();
                if (checkResult == 0)
                {
                    // The record does not exist, write it to the SQL database using SqlBulkCopy.
                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(new[] { csv });
                }
                else
                {
                    // The record already exists, update it using an UPDATE statement.
                    using var updateCommand = new SqlCommand("UPDATE {tablename} SET Column1 = @col1, Column2 = @col2, Column3 = @col3, Column4 = @col4, Column5 = @col5, Column6 = @col6 WHERE TicketID = @value", conn);

                    // Add parameters for each column you want to update, using the names and types of the columns in the target table.
                    updateCommand.Parameters.Add("@col1", SqlDbType.Int, 10, "TicketID");
                    updateCommand.Parameters.Add("@col2", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "TicketTitle");
                    updateCommand.Parameters.Add("@col3", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "TicketStatus");
                    updateCommand.Parameters.Add("@col4", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "CustomerName");
                    updateCommand.Parameters.Add("@col5", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "TechnicianFullName");
                    updateCommand.Parameters.Add("@col6", SqlDbType.DateTime, 50, "TicketResolvedDate");
                    updateCommand.Parameters.Add("@value", SqlDbType.Int, 10, "TicketID");

                    // Set the values of the parameters to the values in the current row of the CSV file.
                    updateCommand.Parameters["@col1"].Value = int.Parse(csv["TicketID"].ToString());
                    updateCommand.Parameters["@col2"].Value = csv["TicketTitle"].ToString();
                    updateCommand.Parameters["@col3"].Value = csv["TicketStatus"].ToString();
                    updateCommand.Parameters["@col4"].Value = csv["CustomerName"].ToString();
                    updateCommand.Parameters["@col5"].Value = csv["TechnicianFullName"].ToString();
                    updateCommand.Parameters["@col6"].Value = DateTime.Parse(csv["TicketResolvedDate"].ToString());
                    updateCommand.Parameters["@value"].Value = int.Parse(csv["TicketID"].ToString());

                    // Execute the update command.
                    updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

            }
            conn.Close();
        }
```

But this gives me an error cause the bulkcopy can't read only one datarow.

Comment: why you didn't do an INSERT like you did with the update?

Comment: great question, answer is simple, didn't think of that to be honest. But also, that would create a very lengthy code, and I was hoping to make it smaller and simpeler.

Comment: I think your solution will have bad performance if you're dealing with a lot of rows. It's usually better to bulk your data into a empty import table and then perform your insert / update for all the rows at once.

Comment: Does your database schema is static? If yes, we can scaffold from database classes and apply BulkCopy into temporary table and apply MERGE operations vial `linq2db` library.

Comment: The problem with what you're suggesting is that I import a CSV daily that always has old rows that will be the same. (unfortunately there is no way around that) so then i would get a lot of duplicates in the import table, which gives problems for the insert / update within sql. That's why i'm doing it earlier within the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siggermannen's comment was the correct suggestion. You should bulk load all of the data into a temp table, then use SQL command(s) to merge the data from the temp table into the destination table. Ideally, you'd do this with a T-Sql [Merge Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). You could also use separate update and insert statements. This requires knowledge of the table columns to create the commands to merge the data. You *can* do this dynamically, by reading querying the INFORMATION_SCHEMA for the tables to determine the columns and keys, and using that to dynamically construct the merge statements. Or, if you know the schema at compile time, you can hard-code the statements which will be significantly easier to develop and test.

```cs
using Sylvan.Data.Csv;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

static void LoadTableCsv(SqlConnection conn, string tableName, string csvFile)
{
    // read the column schema of the target table
    var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = $"select top 0 * from {tableName}"; // beware of sql injection
    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    var colSchema = reader.GetColumnSchema();
    reader.Close();

    // create a temp table to load the data into
    // using the destination table as a template
    cmd.CommandText = $"select top 0 * into #load from {tableName}";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // apply the column schema to the csv reader.
    var csvSchema = new CsvSchema(colSchema);
    var csvOpts = new CsvDataReaderOptions { Schema = csvSchema };
    using var csv = CsvDataReader.Create(csvFile, csvOpts);

    // push *all* data into the temp table
    using var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn);
    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "#load";
    bulkCopy.EnableStreaming = true;
    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(csv);

    // use sql commands to "MERGE" the data into the destination table
    cmd.CommandText = $"""
                        insert into {tableName}
                        select * from #load l
                        where not exists (select * from {tableName} d where d.Id = l.Id)
                       """;

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
```

Doing insert/update statements in a loop is what you're trying to avoid. This produces "chatty" communication with the database where performance becomes dominated by overhead of each operation. Instead, you want to keep your operations as "chunky" as possble, which SqlBulkCopy and MERGE will provide.